software.amazon.awssdk Custom executorService not working
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, new CustomThreadFactory("CustomPool"));

SdkAsyncHttpClient httpClient = NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder()
.maxConcurrency(50)
.connectionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
.writeTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
.build();

S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient = S3AsyncClient.builder()
.httpClient(httpClient)
.region(Region.US_EAST_2)
.credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(
AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey)))
.build();

S3TransferManager transferManager = S3TransferManager.builder()
.s3Client(s3AsyncClient)
.executor(executorService)
.build();

// File upload task
UploadFileRequest uploadFileRequest = UploadFileRequest.builder()
.source(Paths.get(fullPath))
.addTransferListener(LoggingTransferListener.create())
.putObjectRequest(PutObjectRequest.builder()
.bucket(bucketName)
.key(keyFileName)
.build())
.build();

transferManager.uploadFile(uploadFileRequest).completionFuture().thenRun(() -> {
logger.info("Upload completed for: " + keyFileName);
});


Logs:
[main] INFO software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.progress.LoggingTransferListener - Transfer initiated...
[main] INFO software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.progress.LoggingTransferListener - |                    | 0.0%
[main] INFO software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.progress.LoggingTransferListener - Transfer initiated...
[Thread-0] INFO software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.progress.LoggingTransferListener - |====================| 100.0%
[aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-5] INFO software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.progress.LoggingTransferListener - |====================| 100.0%
[sdk-async-response-1-0] INFO com.test.tucm.awssdkv2.demo.S3MultiThreadedUploadTestWithHttpClient - downloaded completed for: download.js
[sdk-async-response-1-0] INFO software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.progress.LoggingTransferListener - Transfer complete!
[sdk-async-response-1-1] INFO com.test.tucm.awssdkv2.demo.S3MultiThreadedUploadTestWithHttpClient - Upload completed for: download.js
[sdk-async-response-1-1] INFO software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.progress.LoggingTransferListener - Transfer complete!

Run the codes.
From the logs, the threads handling upload and download tasks are still using the default thread names (e.g., [Thread-0]), rather than the custom names specified by the CustomThreadFactory. It appears that the custom executorService provided to the S3TransferManager is not being used as expected. Could this be a bug in the S3TransferManager or a misconfiguration in the code?
sdk

software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.29.27

Why is the custom executorService not working as expected in this code? The custom thread names (e.g., CustomPool-1) are not being applied, and the thread name still appears as [Thread-0] in the logs.
